# Django ManyToManyField get records from related model where not in join table

Tags: django, django-views

I am using Django ManyToManyField to assign tags to photos.  I put M2M field in Tags model:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photos)
```

It works fine.  I can get all tags assigned to photo using:

```
photo = Photos.objects.get(id=int(photo_id))
photo_tags = photo.tags_set.all()
```

Then to give user a list of all tags so they can assign them photo I am using:

```
tag_list = Tags.objects.order_by('tag')
```

However, I'd like to limit this list to tags that are not yet assigned to the photo eg where tag is not in join table for that photo.

But stuck on what ORM logic to use here.  Is there something like tags_set_none or filter(tags_set=None) ?

Comment: You can get the ids of those tags and filter the tags directly to include everything but those. I don't know if that's the best approach as that would need 2 queries, but should be a valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tags = Tags.objects.exclude(photos=photo)
```

Comment: Damn that worked! Too easy.  How would I have figured this out on my own from Django documentation? Maybe a handy list of what Django ORM magic is available? Hmm thx